# What is the différence between this type of sockets

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, python-2.x

i want to know what is the difference betwwen this 3 codes who send a socket:

1=)

```
import _socket
n = _socket.SocketType()
n.connect(('www.facebook.com', 443))
```

2=)

```
import _socket
n = _socket.socket()
n.connect(('www.facebook.com', 443))
```

3=)

```
import socket
n = socket.socket()
n.connect(('www.facebook.com', 443))
```

the 2 first codes include the Original DDL Module of the socket in Python , the last Module use the Library (socket), and i want to know who of this codes can connect faster then others?

Comment: 1 and 2 are identical (literally: two different names for the same object type). 3 (`socket.socket`) is a wrapper around the low-level `_socket` object type and therefore theoretically slower. However, that difference will be nanoseconds at most, and you will not be able to detect any difference between them when connecting to a remote website since those nanoseconds are utterly insignificant relative to the many milliseconds it will take to complete a connection across the net. Use `socket.socket` -- it's well-documented, supported, and more portable.

Comment: but i don't understand how _socket are mmore slower then socket and socket are importing _socket ? _socker are faster or slower then socket?

Comment: No; `socket.socket` is theoretically slower *because* it's a wrapper around `_socket`. But they're fundamentally the same mechanism. One just has a couple of extra python methods attached. That won't make *any* difference whatsoever in the observable "speed of execution".

Comment: thanks for answering to that post , i appréciate you'r help!